# get ID of element inside a plugin called on css-selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I have a basic problem. I have this example jquery-plugin, which i want to be run on all divs with a certain css-selector (.myDiv) :

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.testt = function(options) {
    console.log(this.id);
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
  };

}(jQuery));


$(".myDiv").testt({
  'thickness': 3,
  'color': '#ccc'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv" id="myfirstDiv">blablabla</div>
```

How can I get the ID of the div? My code always returns me `undefined`.

Comment: `$(this).attr('id')` would work, `this` is a jQuery object in the `testt()` don't mix it with DOM element. You can also use `this.attr('id')`

Comment: yes, everything is fine with your second alert. I am getting id.

Comment: hi,.. but `$(this).attr('id')` does not work .. this code above gives me 2x undefined

Comment: I have create a snippet for you, See second `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: it gives undefined and then the id. Check it better, dude

Comment: thanks @all :) ... your example works.. but here it only works when I there is no html-wrapper (head/body-tags)

Comment: offtopic: always `return this` from a plugin.  Normally via `each`:  ie `return this.each(function() { ...` to allow for chaining.  (https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is a jQuery object in the `testt()` plugin method, You can use various jQuery method at disposal.

If you have multiple element use `.each()` and in the iterator method

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.testt = function(options) {
    //Here this refers to jQuery object
    this.each(function() {
      //Here, this refers to underlying DOM element, so you can use various method
      console.log(this.id); 
    })    
  };
}(jQuery));


$(".myDiv").testt({
  'thickness': 3,
  'color': '#ccc'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv" id="myfirstDiv">blablabla</div>
<div class="myDiv" id="myfirstDiv2">blablabla</div>
<div class="myDiv" id="myfirstDiv3">blablabla</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

Here id demo: https://output.jsbin.com/pasequp

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="myDiv" id="myfirstDiv">blablabla</div>
<div class="myDiv" id="myfirstDiv1">blablabla</div>
<div class="myDiv" id="myfirstDiv2">blablabla</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
(function ( $ ) {
  $.fn.testt = function( options ) {
    //Merge default and user parameters
     options = $.extend( {minlength: 0, maxlength: 99999}, options);

    //traverse all nodes
     this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
          alert($this.attr('id'));
          //alert(options.thickness);
          //alert(options.color);
       });
   };
}( jQuery ));

$(".myDiv").testt({
    'thickness': 3,
    'color': '#ccc'
});
```